# Listing books in a series

Tags: packages

Are there any package for creating a list of books within a series, i.e. for, listing the chronology of a series (which includes the current book within), or providing a list of other books by the same author?

Comment: Do you mean in the bibliography, or like a table?

Comment: More like a table.

Comment: I don't know of a package for this specific thing I'm afraid. You could put in. You may want to consider doing this as a miniature bibliography. Take a look at chapterbib and multibib. If you're using biblatex, the functionality already exists I think.

Comment: Provide an example of how the output should look.  This doesn't sound very tricky to implement, but maybe you have some esoteric list of books in mind.